# HttpClient.GetJsonAsync() in Blazor on Azure leads to "Invalid JSON string", locally it works just fine. Any idea why?

Tags: c#, azure, blazor

I am playing around with Blazor right now. And I found a strange behaviour and I am not quite sure, if it's my, Azure's or Blazor's (it's still experimental, so it's possible) fault. My project is ASP.NET core hosted (on Azure, but I already told that).

I've got the following model:

```
namespace MyProject.Shared
{
    public class Emoji
    {
        public List<string> UnicodeCharacters { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Emoji()
        {
            UnicodeCharacters = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

The following controller:

```
namespace MyProject.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class EmojiPickerController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<Emoji> GetEmojis()
        {
            var emojis = new List<Emoji>();
            var emoji = new Emoji();
            emoji.Description = "Foo";
            emoji.UnicodeCharacters.Add("Bar");
            return emojis;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my component:

```
namespace MyProject.Client.Classes
{
    public class EmojiPicker : BlazorComponent
    {
        [Inject]
        protected HttpClient Http { get; set; }
        public List<Emoji> Emojis = new List<Emoji>();

        protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
        {
            var emojiArray = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Emoji[]>("api/EmojiPicker/GetEmojis");
            Emojis = emojiArray.ToList<Emoji>();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works just fine when I launch it locally. I've got the object in my view and can do stuff with it (e.g. printing "foo" and "bar" on the screen ;)).

But it's not like that on my Azure WebApp. It just doesn't work:
[image: My error messages]

The WeatherCast sample works btw on both platforms. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, after restarting my Azure application everything works just fine. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after restarting my Azure application everything works just fine. Weird.